# Powershell: How can I pass a variable as a parameter value?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have code that prompts a user for input for $dom.

```
$dom = "'DC=my,DC=com'"

Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $dom -SearchScope 'SubTree' -objectattributes @{"EmployeeID"=$eid} | 
Select-Object SamAccountName, employeeID, DisplayName, Description, Email, LastLogon, legacyExchangeDN
```

I get the following error when I run this.

> Get-QADUser : A referral was returned from the server.
>
> At C:\My Scripts\get-user_by using eid.ps1:62 char:12
>   + Get-QADUser <<<<  -SearchRoot:$dom -SearchScope 'SubTree' -objectattributes @
>   {"EmployeeID"=$eid} | 
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-QADUser], COMException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Ques 
>     t.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.GetUserCmdlet

Answer (score 0):

Removing the nested single quotes solved the issue.

$dom = "'DC=my,DC=com'"